# StartupProbe doesn't work on EKS 1.18 when it's upgraded from 1.17

Tags: amazon-eks, startup-probe

We noticed that StartupProbe works on a new EKS 1.18 cluster but if the cluster is upgraded from 1.17, it doesn't work. Is this a bug on EKS?

Comment: I upgraded my EKS cluster, in the hope to use startupProbe, but it doesn't kick in.  Were you able to find out answer to your question?